# Select rows from a table based on conditions in two columns

Tags: matlab, matlab-table

Let us assume we have the following table `mytable`:

```
                     Name                            id         Factor       Correct
    ___________________________________________    ________    _________    ____________

    'Maria'                                        '7324'      'x'           'Yes'      
    'Lina'                                         '7827'      'x'           'Yes'      
    'Jack'                                         '7831'      ''            'No'      
    'Van'                                          '7842a'     'x'           'No'      
    'Julia'                                        '7842c'     ''            'Yes'
```

I want to select all the rows from `mytable` where Factor = 'x' AND Correct = 'Yes' and assign them into a new table. For the class of each column (for example, the `'Name'` column) we have:

```
class(mytable.Name) = cell
```

I tried this code:

```
newtable = mytable((mytable.Correct == 'Yes') & (mytable.Factor == 'x'))
```

And got the error:

```
Undefined operator '==' for input arguments of type 'cell'
```

I tried a second approach:

```
newtable = mytable((cell2mat(mytable.Correct) == 'Yes') & (cell2mat(mytable.Factor) == 'x'))
```

And this time got the error:

```
Error using cat
Dimensions of matrices being concatenated are not consistent.
```

Which makes sense as 'Yes' is of different size compared to 'No'. I'm thinking of reassign the 'Correct' column with 'Y' and 'N'. However, it's not what I really want. Any recommendations?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since your table contains character arrays in each cell, you can do your comparisons with [`strcmp`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strcmp.html) to extract the desired rows:

```
newtable = mytable(strcmp(mytable.Correct, 'Yes') & strcmp(mytable.Factor, 'x'), :);
```

Which yields the following:

```
newtable = 

     Name        id      Factor    Correct
    _______    ______    ______    _______

    'Maria'    '7324'    'x'       'Yes'  
    'Lina'     '7827'    'x'       'Yes'
```

Note that I used the result of the comparison as the row index, then used [`:`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/colon.html) as the column index to select all columns. You can read [this documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/access-data-in-a-table.html) for more information on the different ways to access data in a table.